# PHP: foreach variable assignment and referencing: how-to?

Tags: php, loops, foreach, substitution

I have an array:
$aPerfparse as 2-dimensional array where index ranges from 0 to n-1,

```
* aPerfparse[index]['label']         -   label of the perfdata  
*                  ['value']         -   actual perfdata  
*                  ['uom']           -   unit of measurement (might be NULL)
```

Need to iterate through each item and set each indexes 'value' and 'label' to a sep. variable based-on the index.

Without a loop, it would be:

```
$value0 = $aPerfdata[0]['value'];  
$value1 = $aPerfdata[1]['value'];
```

What is correct/incorrect about this?:

```
foreach ( $aPerfdata as $key => $value ) {  
    $value$key = $aPerfdata[$key]['value'];  
    $label$key = $aPerfdata[$key]['label'];   
}
```

Similarly, I need to take those stored $value and $label variables and reference them later in a foreach loop.

Without a loop, it would look like:

```
ImageTTFText($img, $fontSize, $fontRotation, 2, $fontSize+2, $oShadow, $fontFile, $label0 . ":" . " " . $value0);  
ImageTTFText($img, $fontSize, $fontRotation, 2, $fontSize+40, $oShadow, $fontFile, $label1 . ":" . " " . $value1);
```

What is correct/incorrect about this?:

```
foreach ( $aPerfdata as $key => $value ) {  
    ImageTTFText($img, $fontSize, $fontRotation, 2, $fontSize+$sz, $oShadow, $fontFile, $label$key . ":" . " " . $value$key);  
    sz=$sz+40;  
}
```

Thank you!

## ====

After everyone's help, I have the following working:

```
foreach ( $aPerfdata as $key => $value ) 
{
    ${'label'.$key} = $aPerfdata[$key]['label'];  
    ${'value'.$key} = $aPerfdata[$key]['value'];  
}

foreach ( $aPerfdata as $key => $value )
{
    ImageTTFText($img, $fontSize, $fontRotation, 2, $fontSize+$sz, $oShadow, $fontFile, ${'label'.$key} . ":" . " " . ${'value'.$key});
    $sz=$sz+40;
}
```

I don't really have a need to flatten the array anymore.  I tried the method mentioned by Mark, but the ImageTTFText function doesn't execute.

Comment: `$label$key` => `${'label'.$key}`

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't execute? Do you get an error? A warning? Can you show us more of your code? The section shown is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do

```
foreach ( $aPerfdata as $value ) {  
    ImageTTFText($img, $fontSize, $fontRotation, 2, $fontSize+$sz, $oShadow, $fontFile, $value['label'] . ":" . " " . $value['value']);  
    $sz=$sz+40;  
}
```

Among other things I think your use of variable variables is incorrect. You should really have something like:

```
${'value'.$key}
```

But really you should just be using an array rather than variable variables - and since you already have an array there's no real need to flatten it (as I show you above).

Comment: I like this, didn't do it initially because I needed each var for a height/width calculation, but I am circumventing that now.  Unfortunately, this doesn't generate the proper images that the function (ImageTTFText) is supposed too.  Not sure why.

Comment: @user then you need to provide a little more detail on what it means not to work

Answer (score 1):

Firstly:

```
$label$key
```

is wrong. Should be:

```
$label.$key
```

You need to concatenate the variables with a dot(.).

Didn't understand the second part of the question.
Can you just paste a var_dump of the array so we can get a clearer understanding of the structure?

Comment: I "clearly don't understand the question" as well. Maybe it's your question, though.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you might be confusing foreach with a simple for loop.

If you have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => red
            [value] => 8
            [uom] => cm
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => green
            [value] => 6
            [uom] => m
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [label] => blue
            [value] => 34
            [uom] => m
        )

)
```

You can access iterate over the keys/values as follows.

```
foreach($arr as $array_key => $array_value)
{
        // obviously you don't need to assign these. it's just for demonstration
        $key = $array_key;
        $label = $array_value['label'];
        $value = $array_value['value'];
        $uom = $array_value['uom'];
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have a two dimensional array. The `foreach` statements iterates through the first dimension for you. This should work:

```
foreach ( $aPerfdata as $item ) {  
    $value = $item['value'];  
    $label = $item['label'];   
}
```

Also, I don't think you should include `$` in your variable name, other than of course in front of the name.

Comment: You clearly don't understand the question or variable variables, suggest you reread or conduct further research.

Comment: @Mark; Yes, I mistunderstood the question as I read it fast. You got me there. But it isn't your place to tell me what I need to research; what makes you think you can insult my intelligence like that?

Comment: I didn't insult your intelligence, I merely suggested you conduct one of two activities: reading more closely (seems perfectly reasonable) or researching your answer further -- the latter option of which could be trivial, and is just that, an option.